# primefaces - Can carousel display other content aside from images?

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I was wondering if Primefaces' `carousel` component can display other html elements
like `<div>`, `<iframe>` or even other html files?

Comment: This is a pretty effortless and rhetorical question. You would already have the answer if you ever bothered to *just try* it yourself. If it works, you'll be happy and you can just move on. If it doesn't work, you *could* ask a question if you don't find any reference in the component documentation which confirms this behaviour.

Comment: BalusC I think it is unfair and ARROGANT to say that just because someone which is just learning primefaces failed doing something which seems EASY for you would automatically mean that the question is already rhetorical.  

Can you please point me to where in the "Primefaces User Guide" on chapter 3.9 from page 50-55 did the documentation talk about rendering normal html elements with normal html tags inside the carousel component? The examples in the documentation used <p:graphicImage value="/images/nature1.jpg"/> and <p:tab title="Godfather Part I"> which are both not native html tags.

Comment: What I meant to say, is that you should rather ask a concrete programming question. E.g. "I am trying to achieve [insert functional requirement] and I have attempted to implement it as follows [insert some code], but it didn't work as expected [insert expectations], instead the following happens [insert actual results]". Your current question is just a Yes-No question which could easily be answered by trying it yourself. This does not really fit on Stackoverflow, see also http://stackoverflow.com/faq But if you really find this arrogant, I don't have any problem to add you to my ignore list :)

Comment: You can still add me to your ignore list if you want to but i really was offended with your first comment. But after reading your second comment no offense taken.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; `carousel` can display *any* type of content in it.

For example, imagine you have a managed bean (`mybean`) storing a list of page URLs (`urls`).
This would display an IFrame pointing to the URL in every cell:

```
<p:carousel value="#{mybean.urls}" var="url">
    <iframe src="#{url}" width="300" height="300"></iframe>
</p:carousel>
```